# Java PKCS12 keystore - Unrecognized keystore format

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore, keytool, pkcs#12

I'm trying to create a PKCS12 keystore using Bouncy Castle Crypto in Java8 and it creates all good.  Now, if I try to load the generated keystore using keytool, it is not able to recognise the format automatically.

i.e. this command fails with below error

`keytool -v -list -keystore my_store.p12`

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: Unrecognized keystore format. Please load it with a specified type
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:1816)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:1687)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:928)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:412)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:405)
```

It is indeed able to load the keystore and display everything just fine if i add the format like below.

`keytool -v -list -keystore my_store.p12 -storetype PKCS12`

Also, it works just fine if I run it using the JDK I used to compile.  I created a wrapper to the JDK's keytool in a class like below and that works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(args);
    }
```

Why is the standalone keytool unable to recognise the format?  How to make the format visible for all keytools to work?

Comment: I guess this is how `keytool` was designed. Up to and including Java 8, JKS was the default keystore format. It probably assumes if you don't use the `storetype` option, the input is JKS and errors out if it's not.

Comment: @automatictester: 8u60 up has a 'compatibility' option that by default automatically reads either JKS or PKCS12 (although it may not _display_ the format id correctly, and it continues to _create_ JKS by default), while 9 up (which OP is obviously using based on the stacktrace format) defaults to creating PKCS12 _and_ can read any format. OP: I agree this should work; can you provide an example file with non-secret (fake or test) key(s)? (Don't post binary on Stack, either use base64 or hex or something like pastebin.)